# how can I apply the np.dot function on two lists in numpy pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two different lists and I have to apply np.dot function of numpy in python
how can I do that?

list1=

```
array([[      nan,       nan],
       [ 0.000829,  0.000326],
       [-0.000149, -0.00033 ],
       ...,
       [-0.000757, -0.000737],
       [-0.000795, -0.00068 ],
       [-0.000788, -0.00069 ]])
```

list2 =

```
array([[      nan,       nan],
       [      nan,       nan],
       [-0.000829, -0.000326],
       ...,
       [ 0.000763,  0.000738],
       [ 0.000757,  0.000737],
       [ 0.000795,  0.00068 ]])
```

these are two seperate list of lists

so I want to do it this way:

```
np.dot([-0.000149, -0.00033 ], [-0.000829, -0.000326])
```

so it is like

```
np.dot(list1[3], list2[3])
```

and it continue to choose one index from one list and one index from the other list 
and that should return the one dimensional array, the problem is data, which is in two seperate list, so I need one index from list one and one index from the other list, i know it can be done through the loop, but not sure how is it possible,

i hope it is clear now

Comment: @lucidbrot yes it is the kind of matrix multiplication

Comment: @timgeb I don't have the output yet, but it after matrix multiplication it should be a one dimensional list

Comment: @id101112 Okay, [apparently the dot function is defined for more shapes than I expected](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) but using `list1 @ list2` is recommended. Your question needs some additional info about what is wrong with `np.dot(list1, list2)` though

Comment: @id101112 `list1` is not a vector, it is a matrix. How do you expect the matrix multiplication to work without transposing either list? And I don't think the result can ever be onedimensional. You have matrixes of shape `Nx2` so it will be at least 2-dimensional, right?

Comment: let me edit my question again, it might not be very cleared,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is actually about how to loop through the lists and call `np.dot` on each corresponding pair. Here's one way to do it, using list comprehension and `zip`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> list2 = list1.copy()
>>> list_of_results = [np.dot(a,b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> list_of_results
[5, 25]
```

If you are not familiar with list comprehension, I advise you to look that up. But you could also do it with a simple for loop:

```
assert list1.shape == list2.shape, "List shapes do not match"
results = []
for inner_list_index in range(list1.shape[0]):
    a = list1[inner_list_index]
    b = list2[inner_list_index]
    res = np.dot(a,b)
    results = results.append(res)
```

This can be reduced to fewer lines:

```
>>> assert list1.shape[0] == list2.shape[0]
>>> results = []
>>> for i in range(list1.shape[0]):
...     results.append(np.dot(list1[i], list2[i]))
...
>>> results
[5, 25]
```

Note that both of these approaches return a normal `list`, not a numpy `ndarray`. This is because appending to numpy arrays is usually not too fast. You could use `np.append()` instead. Or just apply `np.array()` to the result if you need it as an np array again.

Comment: okey yes I just needed this line `[np.dot(a,b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]`  thanks

Comment: No problem! Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you :) and if something is unclear, feel free to ask