# What is the fastest way to iterate over two lists of vectors and get the dot product of every permutation of the vectors?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of vectors such as

```
list1 = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2), ... , (xn,yn)]
list2 = [(p1,q1), (p2,q2), ..., (pm,qm)]
```

Currently, what I am doing is using two for loops to iterate over the two lists
e.g.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        dot_prod = np.dot(list1[i],list2[j])
```

This is fine if the list of vectors is not long, but for large lists of vectors, I find that it is slowing down my function which I am using in an optimization loop.

Is there a faster way to do this without resorting to loops?

Comment: You can find a list comprehensive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53420713/20851944)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
import numpy as np

# assume inputs are np.array, convert first as necessary...
list1 = np.random.rand(10,2)
list2 = np.random.rand(10,2)

# compute all in one fast vectorized call
vectorized_dot_prod = list1 @ list2.T

# assert identical results (within numerical precision)
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        dot_prod = np.dot(list1[i],list2[j])
        assert np.allclose(vectorized_dot_prod[i][j], dot_prod)
```